# Session error in wcf service call through ajax

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, wcf, extjs

I want to know if sessions are maintained through ajax calls.
I have a Sencha(JS) client which makes ajax GET calls to the server.Server side is implemented using WCF C# .Now when I make the first call the session should start and it seems it is starting. but when the application is making the next call which needs the server to retrieve some value from session which it saved in the first call i am getting an error.As the first call where the session is getting set is nt throwing error so I believe session is getting started. But in the 2nd call it is throwing error.

POINT TO BE NOTED : This is only happening when calling through application. If I am calling simply hitting the GET url in browser everything working perfectly.

Please help what could be the reason. I am at a loss.

Comment: My guess WCF is not configured to use session state (not sure how/if it is even possible).

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are mapped using a session cookie.

You should verify that your application is actually forwarding the session cookie in the call that fails. Enumerate all cookies in the call that works and the call that fails and compare.

Continued:

I usually do ajax via a generic handler (.ashx) I use as a facade that in turn calls any sub systems. In this handler I do parameter conversion and json (de)serialization. Maybe you should go for such an approach and not expose your WCF layer?

Comment: +1. This covers one of 2 possible reasons - cookies not coming with request (can be eaisly checked with Fiddler).

Comment: Ok..I got the point...but if the ajax call through sencha is not forwarding session cookie Can Anyone tell me how to manually forward the cookie through Sencha ajax call (ajax proxy) or any javascript ajax call.

Comment: The call that is working , there in response header i am getting this -Set-Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=pph0w1k3ag0v3a1ehde1tvl3; path=/; HttpOnly . I belive I will have to forward this in subsequent calls. HOW TO DO it? should I add a explicit header in the subsequent calls through which I can send it or what ? plz help